# Connectome Datasets Related to Consciousness

Tags: neural-network, data

I am a mathematics student currently looking for [connectome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectome) datasets specifically related to consciousness research. I have mainly looked at the following sites:

https://neurodata.io/

https://db.humanconnectome.org

But, either I am terrible at searching, or there does not seem to be much there, or the pure graphs are not available, and I'd have to construct them myself from MRI data, which is out of scope for my project.

I'm interested in datasets in the form of functional connectivity networks (in some standard format like .graphml or just adjacency matrices), specifically related to consciousness research such as [DoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disorders_of_consciousness), sleep, or possibly on mindfulness meditation.

I should add that my knowledge of connectomics and MRI data is very limited.

**Question(s)**: Could and would anyone refer me to databases or research where such datasets might possibly be obtained?

Comment: I assume you are referring to functional connectivity? Why is calculating FC from MRI data outside the scope of your project?

Comment: Yes, thank you; I have edited the question to be a bit more specific. And to answer your question: my knowledge of such matters is 0, and my project is primarily in pure mathematics, but includes some application. But it's only due to lack of time I guess; perhaps it's not as complicated as I think it is.

Comment: It really isn't that complicated, especially not compared to the complexity in interpreting the resulting graphs. I strongly advise against doing research in the area without more of a learning investment first, or at a minimum going forward together with a close collaborator. Otherwise you will probably find you've wasted most of your time.

Comment: Ok, well I should add that I am a student, and my subject is mathematics, and just as a part of my thesis, I want to study the topology of such networks. This is why I prefer not to go into too much work obtaining the data per se. But I definately agree, and I want to learn more about connectomics anyway, we'll just see if I have time. I'd happily take any suggestions on where best to start learning about the process from fMRI to a graph.

Comment: The most commonly used measure of functional connectivity in fMRI is the correlation coefficient. Start with any primer on fMRI.